# Auth error with POST request: "Authentication credentials were not provided" using Axios, but works using POSTMAN

Tags: reactjs, axios, authorization, postman, token

I'm using React and trying to handle password change by the user. I'm sending a POST request like this:

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/password/change/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
            },
            data: {
                new_password1: newPassword1,
                new_password2: newPassword2
            }
        })
```

...and I get a 401 error: "Authentication credentials were not provided".

However, if I send the exact **same** request via **POSTMAN**, it works fine.

I am also doing GET request in the same app to get user data, and it also works without any problem:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/' + path + '/' + userId + '/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
            }
        })
```

What could be the issue...?

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the token and making a call if that works in the POST request?

Comment: Yes, I have, but thank you for the tip. Still didn't work with axios...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axios.post expects (url, data, config).

So you need to use like this:

```
  axios.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/password/change/",
    {
      new_password1: newPassword1,
      new_password2: newPassword2
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Token ${token}`
      }
    }
  );
```

Docs:

https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config