# POST method working in POSTMAN but shows error from frontend

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I have an api end point that is working fine in POSTMAN but when I try to POST method from frontend axios it gives error

```
JSON
  detail "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

from fontend

```
const config = {
headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    Authorization : `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`
},
};


axios.post(
  `...................................`,
 config, 
)
```

But in POSTMAN it works fine with these Authorization
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFbHd.png)
and Headers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNLI3.png)

but in Browser console it shows error
with this request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDbr7.png)
and for response error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz1nh.png)

I know I am adding unnecessary image links here but that's the best way in which I can show my problem.If you need any other details to debug this or If you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have checked out this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877512/auth-error-with-post-request-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided-usi

Comment: @DarthJS that's not the problem with me that solution said axios.post expects (url, data, config). and I have no data field so mine looks like axios.post (url,config) .Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config
axios.post(url[, data[, config]]) - written in DOC, post method have to contain data, if you don't have a data to post jsut try to put here empty object data = {} OR put there null

Comment: @DarthJS I added data field const data = null; and it worked perfectly.Thank you for replying and answering my question.